# header('Location: '.$page) function not working

Tags: php, header, isset

Can anybody help me? I perform my shop cart using php and in some moment after several customizations my header() function stopped working. I just can not figure why. I appreciate any help.

```
$page = 'index.php';
if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "noivaem", "password", "noivaem") or die (mysqli_error());
    $quantity = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, quantity FROM Products WHERE id=".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['add']));
    while($quantity_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($quantity)) {
        $_SESSION['cart_'.(int)$_GET['add']]+=1;}
    header('Location: '.$page); }
```

Comment: See also the add code:

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string takes the string as the first argument and then the optional connection

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. If it does, report back ;-)

Comment: *"mysqli_real_escape_string takes the string as the first argument and then the optional connection"* - @Mihai you sure about that? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php `string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )` - that's `mysql_` not `mysqli_` ;-)

Comment: please don't do that ^ place that in your question and delete it from comments; it's totally unreadable, thanks.

Comment: I am sorry. I am trying but I am not allowed. Do not know why. Messange: Your code do not appear to be a code.

Comment: Hello Fred, It was fouded two "Undefined variable" errors, one related to $total variable and another one related to my payment system Password that uses the simbol "$". Do you think that there is any relashionship between this errors and the header () function inoperative?

Answer (score 0):

Check to ensure nothing is being output to the browser before `header()`

Hint: You have an error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

After several hours reserching my code, finally I founded what was causing the Header inoperative. There was a specific jquery script avoiding the header to work properly. I removed the jquery script line and know it works fine. My page was disconfigured but I only need to recofingure in a manual way. Thank you for your help anyway. Best regards, Roberto